# L. Jacobsen and H. Waadeland: Glimt fra analytisk teori for kjedebrøker. Del 2.

Tags: continued-fractions, reference-works

I am trying to find the aforementioned paper online but have had no luck.

I originally spotted it as a reference **[26]** for the paper [Gauss, Landen, Ramanujan, the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean, Ellipses, π, and the Ladies Diary](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~berndt/gausslandenmonthly.pdf) (p 607) where it is fully referred to as:

L. Jacobsen and H. Waadeland, Glimt fra analytisk teori for kjedebrøker, Del II, Nordisk Mat. Tidskr., 33 (1985) 168-175.

Comment: I can scan it and email it to you. Just send me an email (check my home page to find it).

Comment: I have now. Thank you very much for going through the trouble of scanning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved – see the comments. I am posting this answer in order to remove the question from the list of unanswered questions.